# Wildcard subdomains htaccess rule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I already setup the dns zone to point `*.user.domain.com`, It works fine but i get the known default cpanel page.

I believe that i have to put something in the htaccess to forward the subdomains requests to a php page.

Example

```
simon.user.domain.com -> hello.php?user=simon
```

I've tried the following rules but they don't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.user.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*)  hello.php?user=%1
```

I've put it in the domain.com public html but as i said it's not working.

Any Ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite cond is *Perl compatiable regular expression*, so no `^` in  parentheses!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.user.domain.com
```